# Debian 8 : New user can't choose password

Tags: linux, debian, passwords, debian-jessie

I have created a new user on my Debian Computer using the user GUI panel.

I have choice :

1. Authorize the new user to choose it password on next login OR
2. Define a password

If I choose the option 1, on next login. But, the system want me to enter a password. What password? I don't know what is the password, and the system said `incorrect password` each time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it should just be a blank password, and then it'll make you change it. I've done this on other distros, but not Debian.

Comment: No isn't blank. Blank return an error.

Comment: And you've tried "password"?